# Power of a polynomial in Galois field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $f(x) \in GF[q](X)$, where $q = p^m$ and $p$ prime. Is the following true?

$$f^{p^m}(X) = f(X^{p^m}).$$

I tried to prove the assertion above and got stuck at the following:

$$
\begin{align}
f^{p^m}(X) &= (f_0 + f_1 X + f_2 X^2 + \ldots f_{n-1}X^{n-1})^{p^m}\\
&= f_0^{p^m} + (f_1 X + f_2 X^2 + \ldots f_{n-1}X^{n-1})^{p^m} + \text{cross products}.
\end{align}
$$

For the assertion to be true, the cross products should go to zero. Once they go to zero, we can keep on applying the binomial theorem to eventually get the proof of our result. If the assertion is not true, we should have some reason for the cross products to be nonzero. Can anyone please guide whether the cross products vanish or not, eventually guiding if the assertion is true or not.

Comment: $p$ divides the coefficients of the cross products.

Comment: @BrL Suppose, $p^m \choose 2$ $= p^m (p^m-1) / 2$. How can we say that $p$ divides the coefficient, when we can't say anything about $(p^m/2)$ whether 2 divides $p^m$ or not. Apologies if I missed some basic detail. Can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: As @Arnaud D. wrote, for $0<k<p$, $\displaystyle \binom{p}{k}$ is divisible by $p$. Indeed, $k!\displaystyle \binom{p}{k} = p(p-1)\cdots (p-k+1)$ is divisible by $p$ but $k!$ is not.

Comment: your notations are just the less explicit that you could find....

Comment: @user1952009 What kind of explicitation would you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a field $K$ of characteristic $p$, the identity
$$(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$$
holds for all $x,y\in K$. The reason is simply that in the binomial expansion
$$(x+y)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{p-k}y^k,$$
the coefficients $\binom{p}{k} = \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ are multiples of $p$ if $0<k<p$, so the corresponding term $\binom{p}{k}x^{p-k}y^k$ is zero.

Now if you define $\Phi:K\to K:x\mapsto x^p$, $\Phi$ is an endomorphism (called the Frobenius endomorphism). This implies that for all $m$, $\Phi^m$ is an endomorphisme as well, and thus
$$f(X^{p^m})=f(\Phi^m(X))= \Phi^m(f(X))=(f(X))^{p^m}.$$

Answer (score 0):

let $f(X)=X$, you have $X^{p^m}\neq X$. But the functions defined by $f$ and 
$f^{p^m}\in GF[X]$ coincide on $GF$. To see this remark that for
 $x\in GF$, 
$f^{p^m}(x)= (f_0+f_1X+...+f_nx^n)=f_0^{p^m}+f_1^{p^m}x^{p^m}+...+f_n^{p^m}(x^n)^{p^m}=f(x)$ this results from the binomial formula, the facts that the characteristic is $p$ and $u^{p^m}=u,u\in GF$.